Issue with Incorrect Distinct Count in Google Looker Studio When Selecting Multiple Years in Filter
I'm working on a project using Google Looker Studio (formerly known as Data Studio) and I'm encountering an issue with a filter control affecting my report. The dataset I'm using is the Iris dataset, and I have a filter control for selecting multiple years (2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024). The report is supposed to display a table with the distinct count of iris species, which should be 3 (Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor, Iris-virginica).
Here's the problem I'm facing:
When I select all years in the filter dropdown, the report correctly shows the distinct species count as 3.
When I select any single year, it also correctly shows the distinct species count as 3.
However, when I select multiple years (e.g., 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023), the distinct species count incorrectly shows larger number instead of 3 .


This issue is preventing me from presenting an accurate report. The distinct count of species should always be 3 regardless of the number of years selected. How can I resolve this discrepancy?
Steps Taken
Added a filter control on the top right corner of the report to select multiple years.
Created a table to display iris species and the distinct count of species.
Observed the distinct species count with different filter selections:
Request for Help
I need assistance in diagnosing and fixing this issue so that the distinct count of species remains accurate (3) regardless of the filter selection. Any guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Ran into the exact same issue. Any chance you figured this out?

Can you share a view link to the dashboard so others can reproduce it?
Or share the dataset link please?

I tried it with Iris.csv available on kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/iris
It does not have years, but I created a years.csv and cross joined with iris to get similar to your dataset.
It's behaving as you'd expect:

